# How to generate Two Random Number in javascript such as the 1st number is always greater than the second?

Tags: javascript

How to generate Two Random Number in javascript such as the 1st number is always greater than the second and also in another code please share how to generate two random number such as the first number is always divisible by the second?

I am trying

```js
var x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
var y = ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1) <= x);

console.log(x, y);
```

but I am only getting the value of x and instead geting the value of y I am getting true or false.

Comment: With operator `<=` you aren't adding contraints to the vale of y. You are just *evaluating* if the randomly generated number is lower than x or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use randojs.com to answer this, so if you want to use my answer, put this in the head tag of your HTML document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Get two random numbers 1 - 100 where the second is always greater:

```
var x = rando(1, 99);
var y = rando(x + 1, 100);
```

Get two random numbers 1 - 100 where the second is always divisible by the first:

```
var a = 2, b = 3;
while(b / a % 1 > 0){
    a = rando(1, 100);
    b = rando(1, 100);
}
```

If you care for a version of this division code that's a tad bit more efficient but more long-winded:

```
var a = rando(1, 100);
var b = rando(1, 100);
while(a * b > 100 && a / b % 1 > 0 && b / a % 1 > 0){
    a = rando(1, 100);
    b = rando(1, 100);
}
if(b / a % 1 > 0){
    if(a / b % 1 == 0){
        var temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp
    }
    else{
        b = a * b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get a number and then the parts of it and select from the parts a value.

```js
function getRandomN(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
}

function getRandom(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function getParts(n) {
    var parts = [],
        i;

    for (i = 1; i < Math.floor(n / 2); i++) {
        if (n % i === 0) parts.push(i);
    }
    console.log(...parts);
    return parts;
}

var value1 = getRandomN(100),
    value2 = getRandom(getParts(value1));

console.log(value1, value2);
```

Comment: You can use `i < Math.floor(n / 2)` since the max part is `n / 2` for even numbers.