# How to get random math number and operator and get the answer of it in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my codes as I want to show and print the random number , operators and the answer of it when I clicked the "New" onclick button. Please help me. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<title>MATH FLASHCARD 1.0</title> 
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 

    <script>
    
        var operators = [{
        sign: "+",
        method: function(num1,num2){ return num1 + num2; }
     },{
        sign: "-",
        method: function(num1,num2){ return num1 - num2; }
     }];

        var selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random()*operators.length);

        operators[selectedOperator].sign                  //this will give you the sign
        operators[selectedOperator].method(rnum1, rnum2)  //this will give you the answer


        function New()
        {
            num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
            num2 - document.getElementById("num2");
            rnum1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
            rnum2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
            num1.innerHTML=rnum1
            num2.innerHTML=rnum2
        }

    </script>
</head> 

<h2>MATH FLASHCARDS V1.0</h2>

<body> 
    <div> 
    <div id="num1"></div><!--end of num1-->
    <div id="num2"></div><!--end of num2-->
    <div id="operators"></div><!--end of operator-->  
    <div id="answer"></div><!--end of answer-->
    <button onclick="New()">New</button>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this is the result you are looking for:

```js
let operators = [{
  sign: "+",
  method: function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
  }
}, {
  sign: "-",
  method: function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
  }
}];

function New() {
  const num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  const num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  const operatorEl = document.getElementById("operators");
  const answerEl = document.getElementById("answer");

  const rnum1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  let rnum2;
  do{
   rnum2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
  }while(rnum2 > rnum1)
  const selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length);

  const operator = operators[selectedOperator] //this will give you the sign
  const answer = operator.method(rnum1, rnum2) //this will give you the answer

  num1.innerHTML = rnum1
  num2.innerHTML = rnum2
  operatorEl.innerHTML = operator.sign;
  answerEl.innerHTML = answer
}
```

```html
<h2>MATH FLASHCARDS V1.0</h2>
<div>
  <div id="num1"></div>
  <!--end of num1-->
  <div id="num2"></div>
  <!--end of num2-->
  <div id="operators"></div>
  <!--end of operator-->
  <div id="answer"></div>
  <!--end of answer-->
  <button onclick="New()">New</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Can I ask if how can I make it into a complex one that if the first number must always be greater than the second number to have a positive output only? Thanks in advance again.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Please explain what the problem was and how you fixed it in your answer.

Comment: I edited my snippet so that the result never become less than zero. but there is another question about this topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115010/how-to-generate-two-random-number-in-javascript-such-as-the-1st-number-is-always) you can check out this question also.

Comment: I think the problem in your code was that, you just generate new numbers in your New method, you should get new numbers and operator every time button has clicked

Comment: @SaeedShamloo hi, your codes is actually what I'm using right now and it works. I don't know who gave you a downvote answer. Can I contact you? Do you have any messaging platform like whatsapp or messenger so that I can ask you some questions regarding this one?

Comment: We can chatting each other here on stackoverflow

Comment: @SaeedShamloo how can we chat here? please teach me cause I'm new here lol

Comment: could you join: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239916/newjsdev

Comment: @SaeedShamloo Hi, in order for me to type/talk in the chat, I need to have 20 reputation here first.

Comment: Ok, my telegram id is: sa_shamloo

Comment: I donwvoted for a code-only answer. I commented that when I downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to read the errors in the console. In this case the errors clearly explain exactly what is wrong with your code.

First, declare your variables.

Then put your code that determines the answer in the function so that it's actually called.

Then call the function and actually do something with the output. I just put in in the console.

```js
var num1, num2, rnum1, rnum2, sign, answer;

var operators = [{
  sign: "+",
  method: function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
  }
}, {
  sign: "-",
  method: function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
  }
}];



New();

function New() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  rnum1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  rnum2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  num1.innerHTML = rnum1
  num2.innerHTML = rnum2
  
  
  var selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length);

  sign = operators[selectedOperator].sign //this will give you the sign
  answer = operators[selectedOperator].method(rnum1, rnum2) //this will give you the answer

  console.log('sign:', sign, 'answer:', answer);
}
```

```html
<h2>MATH FLASHCARDS V1.0</h2>

<div>
  <div id="num1"></div>
  <!--end of num1-->
  <div id="num2"></div>
  <!--end of num2-->
  <div id="operators"></div>
  <!--end of operator-->
  <div id="answer"></div>
  <!--end of answer-->
  <button onclick="New()">New</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you and very appreciated, but I need to display the answer in the html itself.

Comment: @MiggyCastillo - Stack overflow is not a fee code writing service. If you want me to write your app for you you're going to have to pay me. I fixed your errors and explained what you did wrong.